# I want to show result of first four characters from text field 1 + field 2 full in javascript + HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show result of first four characters from text field 1 + field 2 full in javascript + HTML

Here is the sample code

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value +''+ txtLastName.value">
First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" /> <br><br>
Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" /> <br><br>
Full name : <input type="text" name="txtFullName"  > <br><br>
</form>
```

but in full name i want only to display first four characters of first name + last name full

if possible in full last name space i need to show dob selection

Comment: have mentioned the piece of code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to make a simple change... using substr() will do the trick.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value.substr(0, 4) +' '+ txtLastName.value">
First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" /> <br><br>
Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" /> <br><br>
Full name : <input type="text" name="txtFullName"  > <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks , could u help me more?? In wordpress when i use this code onclick event disappears when I switch the visual and text tab. Any fix on this, please me with creating external ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr(0, 4)` to get the first four characters for each fields.

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value.substr(0, 4) +' '+ txtLastName.value.substr(0, 4)">
First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" /> <br><br>
Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" /> <br><br>
Full name : <input type="text" name="txtFullName"  > <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks ankit, could u help me more?? In wordpress when i use this code onclick event disappears when I switch the visual and text tab. Any fix on this, please me with creating external ones.

Comment: @CJJunior you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var fName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value.substr(0,4);
var lName = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
document.getElementById("txtFullName").value = fName + " " + lName;
```